# Python - unpacking args not working as expected

Tags: python, class

I'm a Python beginner and building a quiz app. I have a class for the quiz with a method that resets the status of some entrants.

The plan is that if those entrants are on the list of winners or losers, they're removed and put back into the list of contestants.

```
def reset(self, *entrants):
    for e in entrants:
        if e in self.__winners:
            self.__winners.remove(e)
        if e in self.__losers:
            self.__losers.remove(e)
        self.__contestants.append(e)
```

When I call the function, I get different results depending on how I supply the args. For example, I have two people - Andy who is a winner and Bob who is a loser. If I supply their names to the function as below the first two calls work as intended and the last one doesn't.

```
    entrants = ["Andy", "Bob"]

    foo = quiz.Quiz(entrants)

    foo.winners = "Andy"
    foo.losers = "Bob"

    # foo.reset("Andy", "Bob") <-- works fine when uncommented
    # foo.reset(*["Andy", "Bob"]) <-- works fine when uncommented
    # foo.reset(*entrants) <-- gives wrong result

    print(foo.winners)
    print(foo.contestants)
    print(foo.losers)
```

Correct output (first two)

```
[]
['Andy', 'Bob']
[]
```

Incorrect output (final one)

```
['Andy']
[]
['Bob']
```

What is going on here and why does *entrants give a different result to *["Andy", "Bob"]?

EDIT: Here is the full quiz class as suggested in the comments below:

```
class Quiz:

    def __init__(self, contestants):
        self.contestants = contestants
        self.__winners = []
        self.__losers = []

    @property
    def winners(self):
        return self.__winners

    @winners.setter
    def winners(self, *args):
        for a in args:
            self.__winners.append(a)
            self.contestants.remove(a)

    @property
    def losers(self):
        return self.__losers

    @losers.setter
    def losers(self, *args):
        for a in args:
            self.__losers.append(a)
            self.contestants.remove(a)

    def reset(self, *args):
        for a in args:
            if a in self.__winners:
                self.__winners.remove(a)
            if a in self.__losers:
                self.__losers.remove(a)
            self.contestants.append(a)
```

Comment: Wild guess: `quiz.Quiz(entrants)` is clearing or otherwise modifying the list being passed to it.  Add a `print(entrants)` to make sure the list still has the contents you think it does.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] including at least the class definition and `__init__` method.

Comment: ```*args``` means separate arguments. ```["Andy", "Bob"]``` is a single argument containing a list. Your code does not unpack a list object as an arg, it unpacks a list of arguments

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper, I think you've got it. When I set the winner, it removes them from self.contestants, but self.contestants points to the original list. Thanks. Mystery solved.